# Google Cloud Storage browser console - download files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Is there a way to use gsutil in the browser-based console to download files to a local machine? We can't install the SDK right now to our machines, so looking for alternatives to bulk download files from our Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: What's the restriction on installing the SDK? You could install potentially gsutil standalone or via PyPI, if that is easier.

Comment: We're behind a firewall and our IT hasn't been helpful/responsive in getting around that. Tried gsutil standalone but get an `unable to connect to accounts.google.com during OAUth2 flow` message.

Comment: There's no way to use gsutil in the browser console.  Does your IT department use an HTTP proxy?  If so, you can configure gsutil to work with that, see the proxy section in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq#troubleshooting

Comment: On this [help page](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/examples#manage_cloud_storage_data) it states that gsutil can be used for copying and moving storage data in the Cloud Shell (browser console). Is this different from what you mean?

Comment: Cloud Shell operates on a VM, and doesn't have access to the local machine.  So I don't think this will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, was kind of thinking that was the case. Guess we'll talk with our IT about configuring gsutil with proxy.